# Redis configuration for production

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, master-slave

I'm developing project with redis.My redis configuration is normal redis setup configuration.

I don't know how should I do redis configuration? Master-Slave? Cluster?

Do you have anything suggestion redis configuration for production?

Answer (score 2):

Standard approach would be to have one master and at least one slave.  Depending on your I/O requirements and number of ops/sec, you can always have multiple read-only slaves.  Slaves can be read from but not written to.  So you'll want to design your application to take advantage of doing round-robin requests to the slaves and writes only to the single master.

Depending on your data storage/backup requirement, you can set fsync for append-only mode to be every second.  So while this means you can lose up to one second worth of data, it's really much less than that because your slaves serve as hot backups, and they will have the data within milliseconds.

You'll at least want to do a BGSAVE every hour to get a dump.rdp produced.  You can then save this file live while the server is still running, and store it to some off-site backup facility.

But if you're just using Redis as a standard memcache replacement and don't care about data, then you can ignore all of this.  Much of it will be changing in Redis Cluster in the 3.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your Read/Writes requirements are. Could you give us more informations on that matter ?

> I think 10,000 people use instant my application.I persist member login token on redis.It's important for me.If I don't write redis, member don't login on application.

Even a Redis single instance will be enough to process 10K users (start redis-bench to the throughput available), so just to be sure use a Master/Slave configuration with autopromotion of the slave if the master goes down.

Since you want persistence, use RDB (maybe along with AOF), see [**this topic on Redisio**](http://redis.io/topics/persistence).

Comment: I think 10,000 people use instant my application.I persist member login token on redis.It's important for me.If I don't write redis, member don't login on application.